# Need Help Summing only numbers in a column that contains special characters and numerals in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

```
Name Text
a      0
b      1
c      3
d      8
e      !
f      "
g      a
h      h
i      9

Select name, Sum(Text)
from
(select name, to_number(Text) Text
from Table_Name)

group by name
```

I get an invalid number error code when i run this on oracle assistant.

I am using Oracle 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: What kind of numbers are possible in your text column? Can they be negative? Can a positive number be preceded by + (the "plus" sign)? Can there be spaces around the numbers - and in that case, do you want to ignore them? Can the numbers be fractional, such as 3.5? - and if so, what is your decimal separator? Can the numbers look like 32,000 - representing "thirty-two thousand"?

Answer (score 0):

`Regexp_like` might help you decide which text values are valid numbers; something like this:

```
SQL> with test (name, text) as
  2    (select 'a', '0' from dual union all
  3     select 'b', '1' from dual union all
  4     select 'c', '3' from dual union all
  5     select 'd', '8' from dual union all
  6     select 'g', 'a' from dual union all
  7     select 'i', '9' from dual
  8    )
  9  select sum(text)
 10  from test
 11  where regexp_like(text, '^\d+$');

 SUM(TEXT)
----------
        21

SQL>
```

Comment: This assumes the TEXT numbers (the actual numbers) can only be non-negative *integers*, and they can't look like 1,200 for example (for one thousand two hundred), with the comma as group separator. Perhaps the answer will suffice, but maybe not.

Comment: Right, @mathguy. Example is based on sample data.

Comment: Well - that's true. But I hope in real life developers don't just assume that the sample data given to them by business users is "the whole story". Asking questions like the ones I posted as a Comment under the OP's question is, in my opinion, an important best practice. Simply saying "I answered the question the way it was asked" is not a best practice - again, in my opinion.

Comment: Everything you said (here and there) is correct, @mathguy. Though, this is not *real life*, this is the OP asking a question and us answering it :) I can't remember I've ever seen a table as the one posted above nor can I imagine what would be its purpose. Maybe it is a simple homework. Maybe it is oversimplified problem. Maybe ... who knows? We know what we've been told.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Oracle?  In 12.2 or later, you can

```
select name, sum( to_number( text default 0 on conversion error ))
  from your_table
 group by name;
```

In earlier versions, I generally prefer something like

```
create or replace function safe_to_number( p_str in varchar2 )
  return number
is
  l_ret number;
begin
  l_ret := to_number( p_str );
  return l_ret;
exception
  when others then
    return null;
end;

select name, safe_to_number( text )
  from your_table
 group by name
```

Regular expression based solutions that look for numbers can work but they tend to get complicated quickly.  "1.00" may be a number (assuming the decimal separator is the period), "1.00.00" is not, "-100" is a number "1-00" is not, etc.  You can generally play with the regular expression for a while so that it works with whatever data you have but it's hard to be confident that you've covered every case.  If you decide that you want to handle special cases differently (i.e. you have Indian users that enter one hundred thousand as 1,00,000) then you can update the function to iterate through a series of format masks before giving up on the conversion.

Comment: I am using version 4.0.3.16. I tried to run the query and it says i am missing right parenthesis

Comment: @Deno - There is no version 4.0.3.16 of Oracle.  Oracle was at version 8.1.5 when I graduated back in 1998.  What does `select * from v$version` return?  Which of the two versions is throwing an error?  I did have a syntax error in the initial query, just fixed

Comment: - I am sorry , the version is 11g ...11.2.0.3.0

Comment: @Deno - OK.  Then the `default 0 on conversion error` approach isn't an option.  Does the `safe_to_number` approach work for you?